# Use jq to replace txt file array string values from dictionary

Tags: arrays, json, bash, dictionary, jq

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
  "uid": "d6fc3e2b-0001a",
  "name": "ABC Mgmt",
  "type": "host"
}
{
  "uid": "d6fc3e2b-0002a",
  "name": "Server XYZ",
  "type": "group"
}
{
  "uid": "d6fc3e2b-0003a",
  "name": "NTP Primary",
  "type": "host"
}
{
  "uid": "d6fc3e2b-0004a",
  "name": "H-10.10.10.10",
  "type": "host"
}
```

Then I have a txt file:

```
"d6fc3e2b-0001a"
"d6fc3e2b-0001a","d6fc3e2b-0002a","d6fc3e2b-0003a"
"d6fc3e2b-0004a"
```

Expected Output:

```
"ABC Mgmt"
"ABC Mgmt","Server XYZ","NTP Primary"
"H-10.10.10.10"
```

I have some trouble to make jq using an array which is not json format. I tried various solutions that I found, but none of them worked. I am rather new to scripting, need some help.

```
input=file.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
{
value=$(jq -r --arg line "$line" \
  'from_entries | .[($line | split(","))[]]' \
  dictionary.json)
echo $name
}
done < "$input"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following solution, the dictionary file is read using the `--slurpfile` command-line option, and the lines of "text" are read using `inputs` in conjunction with the -n command-line option.  The -r command-line option is used in conjunction with the `@csv` filter to produce the desired output.

#### Invocation

```
jq -n -R -r --slurpfile dict stream.json -f program.jq stream.txt
```

#### program.jq

```
(INDEX($dict[]; .uid) | map_values(.name)) as $d
| inputs
| split(",")
| map(fromjson)
| map($d[.])
| @csv
```

#### Caveat

The above assumes that the quoted values in stream.txt do not themselves contain commas.

If the quoted values in stream.txt do contain commas, then it would be much easier if the values given on each line in stream.txt were given as JSON entities, e.g. as an array of strings, or as a sequence of JSON strings with no separator character.

### Solution to problem described in a comment

#### Invocation

```
< original.json jq -r --slurpfile dict stream.json -f program.jq
```

#### program.jq

```
 (INDEX($dict[]; .uid) | map_values(.name)) as $d
 | .source
 | map($d[.])
 | @csv
```

Comment: The original stream.txt was queried from a JSON file in following format. 
{
"source" : [ "d6fc3e2b-0001a", "d6fc3e2b-0002a" ]
}
{
"source" : [ "d6fc3e2b-0002a", "d6fc3e2b-0003a", "d6fc3e2b-0004a" ]
}

Is there other way to get the same result directly from the stream JSON entities?

Comment: Yes, that makes things much simpler!

Comment: I'm a beginner with this. Can you provide the solution to getting the results from JSON stream?

Comment: See "Solution to problem described in a comment".